# How to change the text in textbox with change of selected item in combobox?

Tags: c#, ssms-2012

I have a `combobox` `cmbCity` and `textbox` `txtReference`. At the form load the combobox retrieves the cities from database which I managed to do. I want the textbox to change the refrence no. stored in database with change of selected city in combobox for which i need help . I'm using visual studio 2012 and SSMS 2012.

Comment: Can you provide some more information. Like the table that you are querying for `reference no` etc.

Comment: The table contains columns named `cityname` and `refrence_no`. The sql query would be `Select refrence_no from tbl_city where cityname = 'London'`. The above query gives desired answer in ssms.

Comment: do you want only change in textbox the reference no without saving automatically?

Comment: i just want corresponding refrence no to appear in the textbox with change of selected item in combo box eachtime. i dont want to save anything.

Comment: I'm a bit confused(correct me if I'm wrong): for example when you Load the City in the combobox and you select London in the textbox appears a reference_no, when you change the City in the combobox(for example Rome) you want automatically update the reference_no in the textbox?

Comment: yes exactly that. And my cites are obtained from database at formload

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
private void cmbCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=YourSERVER;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;User ID=DBUserName;Password=DBPassword");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from yourTable where someCondition=true",con);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        txtReference.Text = dt.Rows[0]["refrence_no"].ToString();
}
```

It is not a wise-idea to query the the DB on every selection - however i went along the way you asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

In form load you can attach a `DataTable` to the `combobox.datasource`, then set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`. After that in `combobox selectedindexchange` event you' ll manage the `ValueMember`. The code is something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("connString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable;",sql);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        cmbCity.DataSource = dt;
        cmbCity.DisplayMember = "cityname";
        cmbCity.ValueMember = "refrence_no";
        txtReferenceNo.Text = cmbCity.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void cmbCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtReferenceNo.Text = cmbCity.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: it gives `System.Data.DataRowView` in the txtReference.